# Infinity Loop when trying to display Firebase Realtime DB List

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, infinite-loop

I try to create a simple app, where I can input a number, this gets stored in the Firebase Realtime DB under my UserID and if I want to all Data in the Realtime DB gets Displayed.
I have a file named readDB with the following code :

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap'
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-analytics.js";
  import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile, sendEmailVerification  } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-auth.js"
  import { getDatabase, ref, set, onValue } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-database.js";
  //components
 import RenderArray from '../RenderArray';
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

//firebase     
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyBgoMjqs2soEsMlcgb3AztqjoDQuD5Dly8",
      authDomain: "moneyapp-5f530.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "moneyapp-5f530",
      storageBucket: "moneyapp-5f530.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "800356072567",
      appId: "1:800356072567:web:b32b2359111e2acc761a72"
    };
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth();



const LoadHistory = () => {
  const array = [] //über den Funktion Scope kommen
  const [content, setContent] = useState('')
  //load history
  function load() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user != null) {
        
        const displayName = user.displayName;
        const email = user.email;
        const photoURL = user.photoURL;
        const emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
        const userId = user.uid;
        const db = getDatabase();
        const historyRef = ref(db, 'users/' + userId);
        onValue(historyRef, (snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            const childData = childSnapshot.val();
            array.push(childData.note);
            console.info(childData)
            console.info(childKey)
          })
        })
        console.log(array)
        
      }
    })}
    setContent(<div>
      {array.map((note) => (
      <div className="user">{note}</div>
      ))}
      </div>)
load();


    return (
      <div>
         {content}
      </div>
    )
}

export default LoadHistory
```

This is simple for loading the Realtime DB List and putting it into the content variable, which gets directed to the body of a fancy bootstrap list item

I write my data in the following way

```js
function writeUserData(note) {

    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user != null) {
            const displayName = user.displayName;
            const email = user.email;
            const photoURL = user.photoURL;
            const emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
            const userId = user.uid;
            const db = getDatabase();
            const noten = ref(db, 'users/' + userId);
            const newNote = push(noten)
            set(newNote,{
                note
            });
        } else {
          console.log('Not logged in ')
        }
      });
```

For all those, who don't know what I mean with "note". This is a fancy german Name for the number I want to Display. It means something like grade, because I want something like a grade log and in germany grades are numbers
Enough of Germany xD
Thanks for everybody trying to help

Everytime I use "useState" in this funktion a infinity loop gets generated, so I tried to extract to map Part to list the data and simple hand the data over to this part and hand it back to the body. Doesn't work
First a had a couple of issues with the array and object things and so on, but this issue I can't solve.

Comment: You just shared your Firebase config to the world. If you don't have good security rules, that means anyone can read and write your data.

Comment: Yeah I shared the config, but the data I have there is not important, the project is not important. And users are only allowed to write and read data inside their id, nowhere else.